Issue with "Invalid Array Length" Error When Uploading Large Videos Using YouTube API v3
I am attempting to upload videos to YouTube via the YouTube API v3 from my Flutter web application. The upload process works as expected for smaller videos, but when attempting to upload a larger video (e.g., 200MB), I encounter the error: "Invalid array length," and the upload fails.
Below is the relevant portion of my code:
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'dart:async'; // For Stream
import 'dart:convert'; // For JSON decoding
import 'dart:io'
    as io; // For File handling (conditionally for non-web platforms)
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/youtube/v3.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data'; // For Uint8List
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'; // For kIsWeb

class UploadVideoButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const UploadVideoButton({
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  });

  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  @override
  State<UploadVideoButton> createState() => _UploadVideoButtonState();
}

class _UploadVideoButtonState extends State<UploadVideoButton> {
  bool isUploading = false;
  double uploadProgress = 0.0;

  // Replace these placeholders with your Google API credentials
  static const String clientId = //value removed from here ;
  static const String clientSecret = //value removed from here;
  static const String refreshToken = //value removed from here;
  static const List<String> scopes = [YouTubeApi.youtubeUploadScope];
  Future<void> uploadVideo() async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        isUploading = true;
        uploadProgress = 0.0;
      });

      // Authenticate and get an authorized client
      var authClient = await _getAuthClient();
      final youtubeApi = YouTubeApi(authClient);

      // Pick a video file
      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.video,
      );

      if (result != null) {
        Uint8List? fileBytes = result.files.single.bytes;
        //String? filePath = result.files.single.path;

        // Use fileBytes for web or if path is unavailable
        Uint8List fileData = fileBytes!;

        // For non-web platforms, you may still want to use the file path (commented out here)
        // if (filePath != null && !kIsWeb) {
        //   fileData = io.File(filePath).readAsBytesSync();
        // }

        int totalBytes = fileData.length;

        // Create byte stream compatible with YouTube API
        Stream<List<int>> byteStream = Stream.fromIterable(
            [fileData.buffer.asUint8List()]); // Wrap bytes into List<int>

        // Progress-tracking stream
        var progressStream = _createProgressStream(byteStream, totalBytes);

        var video = Video();
        video.snippet = VideoSnippet()
          ..title = 'Sample Video Title'
          ..description = 'Uploaded via Flutter App'
          ..tags = ['Flutter', 'YouTube API'];
        video.status = VideoStatus()..privacyStatus = 'public';

        var media = Media(progressStream, totalBytes);

        // Upload the video
        var response = await youtubeApi.videos.insert(
          video,
          ['snippet', 'status'],
          uploadMedia: media,
        );

        setState(() {
          isUploading = false;
        });

        // Show success message
        _showSnackbar(
            'Video uploaded successfully: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${response.id}');
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isUploading = false;
        });
        _showSnackbar('No video selected');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        isUploading = false;
      });
      _showSnackbar('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  Stream<List<int>> _createProgressStream(
      Stream<List<int>> sourceStream, int totalBytes) {
    int bytesSent = 0;
    const chunkSize = 256 * 1024; // 256 KB per chunk (adjust as necessary)

    return sourceStream.asyncMap((chunk) async {
      bytesSent += chunk.length;

      // Update progress
      setState(() {
        uploadProgress = bytesSent / totalBytes;
      });

      return chunk;
    });
  }

  /// Authenticates and returns an authorized client
  Future<AuthClient> _getAuthClient() async {
    final tokenEndpoint = Uri.parse('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token');
    final response = await http.post(tokenEndpoint, body: {
      'client_id': clientId,
      'client_secret': clientSecret,
      'refresh_token': refreshToken,
      'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    });

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to refresh token: ${response.body}');
    }

    final Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
    final credentials = AccessCredentials(
      AccessToken(
        'Bearer',
        json['access_token'],
        DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: json['expires_in'])).toUtc(),
      ),
      null,
      scopes,
    );

    return authenticatedClient(http.Client(), credentials);
  }

  /// Displays a snackbar with a message
  void _showSnackbar(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        if (isUploading)
          Container(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  //CircularProgressIndicator(value: uploadProgress),
                  //SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Text(
                    'Uploading... ${(uploadProgress * 100).toStringAsFixed(2)}%',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        if (!isUploading)
          SizedBox(
            width: widget.width,
            height: widget.height,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: uploadVideo,
              child: const Text('Upload Video'),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

NOTE
also progress text are not working as excepted ..it shows 0% then 100% after upload is almost done

use readStream and not bytes that can be extremely huge
